# Which .NET Core 2.0 APIs are not compatible with .NET Standard 2.0?

Tags: c#, .net-core, .net-standard-2.0

Googling only reveals that there are like 20+ APIs in .NET Core 2.0 which are missing in .NET Standard 2.0, but which ones exactly? Where can I find the complete list?

Comment: I don't think there's an (easily accessible, ready to digest) list of APIs. .NET Standard's list of APIs is [generated programmatically](https://github.com/dotnet/standard/blob/master/docs/versions/netstandard2.0_ref.md), but .NET Core's list of APIs is not (and I believe it can even actually vary a bit with platform, but I'm not sure about that). If [CoreFX](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/) generates (or can be induced to generate) an API list, comparing them would be relatively simple. https://apisof.net also knows, but that's [not open](https://github.com/terrajobst/apisof.net/issues/4).